# Group logging messages in different threads

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, slf4j, log4j

I have multiple threads running and want to group the log output of each thread so
that it shows all the thread messages in a row after the thread finished running.
I want to log to only one file (almost all other questions regarding thread logging were about logging to different files for each thread).

Currently I'm using **slf4j & log4j**. I would need to have some message queue and flush it after the thread finished. I could do it easiyly by myself but does these logging frameworks provide anything for this case? I know I can set an appender to "auto flush = false" but I don't know if there is some way to group the messages per thread.

many thanks in advance

Comment: You should the log to different log files per thread if really necessary. Otherwise to some post processing on the log file after finished to group threads. Grouping log messages while running the program decrease the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate log file for each thread using slf4j and logback. I tried and it works.